# Is is possible to compare strings with different order using python3

Tags: python, string, artifactory-query-lang

I have two strings (which are actually AQL). is there a way I can compare between them even if the order is not the same (I want to get true for the below as all values are equal)?

```
'items.find({"repo": "lld-test-helm", "path": "customer-customer", "name": "customer-customer-0.29.3.tgz", "type": "file"})'

'items.find({"name": "customer-customer-0.29.3.tgz", "path": "customer-customer", "type": "file", "repo": "lld-test-helm"})'
```

Comment: How do you end up with those strings with methods being called on them?

Comment: @eyllandesc why did you get rid of the string formatting?

Comment: you need to clarify whether you have full strings including the method or not.

Comment: @roganjosh it's related to artifacoty AQL, so I can't really control the order I'm getting it

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Do you get those actual strings or do you create them yourself? I've rolled this back before it gets more confusing, but you've given zero detail on what's going on

Comment: One I created, second got from the server (Originally I sent it in the same order, but then I noticed that it in the server it mix the order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with:

```
input_1 = 'items.find({"repo": "lld-test-helm", "path": "customer-customer", "name": "customer-customer-0.29.3.tgz", "type": "file"})'
input_2 = 'items.find({"name": "customer-customer-0.29.3.tgz", "path": "customer-customer", "type": "file", "repo": "lld-test-helm"})'
```

Strip the `items.find()` call from around the dict:

```
input_1 = input_1[11:-1]
input_2 = input_2[11:-1]
```

or if you want to be more general:

```
input_1 = input_1[input_1.find('{'):input_1.rfind('}')+1]
input_2 = input_2[input_2.find('{'):input_2.rfind('}')+1]
```

As far as determining equality of the two dictionary strings from that point, they must be converted into actual dictionaries.

You can use the the method suggested by jez (`ast.literal_eval()`) if you like, though I personally would use `json.loads()` for this purpose:

```
import json

dict_1 = json.loads(input_1)
dict_2 = json.loads(input_2)
```

Then you simply compare the two dictionaries:

```
dict_1 == dict_2
```

Which in this case will return `True`

Answer (score 2):

Those two strings are valid Python `dict` literals. So let's convert them to `dict` objects:

```
a = '{"repo": "lld-test-helm", "path": "customer-customer", "name": "customer-customer-0.29.3.tgz", "type": "file"}'

b = '{"name": "customer-customer-0.29.3.tgz", "path": "customer-customer", "type": "file", "repo": "lld-test-helm"}'

import ast
a = ast.literal_eval(a)
b = ast.literal_eval(b)
```

...and then just compare them:

```
print(a==b)   # prints:  True
```

Comment: You've conveniently just dropped `items.find()`, no?

Comment: Sure. Instructions for removing those characters can be supplied if anybody truly needs that.

Comment: Well, they're in the strings.

Comment: @jez python ast in only from python 3.8 no? is there a solution for lower version?

Comment: @arielma you could do something similar with json. Refer to: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-string-dictionary-to-dictionary/

Comment: @arielma you must be thinking of something else.  `ast.literal_eval` has been there since 2.6